# TypingError: non-precise type pyobject

Tags: python, numba, jit

I'm trying to apply `numba`  to my class `ShuffleWindow1D`:

```
class ShuffleWindows1D:
    def __init__(self, win=2):
        self.win = win

    @nb.jit(nopython=True)
    def calc(self, data):  
        data = np.array(data, np.float64)
        samples = int(np.floor(len(data)/self.win))
        
        #check how many win_size is off
        margin = len(data)%4
        
        xwin = [data[i*samples:(i+1)*(samples+1)] for i in range(self.win)]
        
        #append margin
        if margin != 0:
            xwin.append(data[-margin:])
        
        
        np.random.shuffle(xwin)
        return xwin
```

However, when assuming the data `data = np.array([1, 3, 5, 6])`, I obtain the following error:

```
TypingError: non-precise type pyobject
During: typing of argument at C:\Users\D.Albert-Weiss\Desktop\Codes\DataPreprocessing\lib\augmentation\augment.py (97)
```

Can someone hint to me where the mistake is?

Comment: Numba support for classes is [still preliminary](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html). You should ideally factor out your `calc` method as a simple function

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of this.